# .htaccess RewriterRule - redirecting to index of site

Tags: .htaccess

I've got the following Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Indexes

RewriteRule ^/#/why-us/44534/$ http://www.new-site.com/why-us/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/#/about-us/33945/$ http://www.new-site.com/about-us/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

I've put this in the .htaccess file in the root of my site. However, when visiting:
www.old-site.com/#/why-us/44534 I just get the 'Index of /' page for old-site.com

Not sure why the url structure of old site has /#/ at the start, but it's not something I can control!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because browser doesn't send any request to web server for URL part after hash sign that's why for a URL of: `www.old-site.com/#/why-us/44534` browser just sends `www.old-site.com/` to web server while trying to scroll down page to an undefined tag `why-us/44534`.

Comment: Oh ok..... Is there any work around? For example... Could I write something with php to capture the full url including that after the hash?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, any workaround will need you to edit these hyperlinks. Or else if these links have some kind of HTML id defined then you can capture clicks using jquery's onclick events and alter the hrefs accordingly.